# How to print the public key of a certificate (Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, certificate

I have a certificate .p12 and .crt and I would like store the public key to print it and use the key with an iPhone application. I have seen the iPhone's documentation, but I can't do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is surprisingly easy.  You don't need to add the certificate to the keychain to handle this case.  Rather, just load the certificate data (that is, the contents of a .cer file) in your application (you can either get this from your bundle or off the network) and then create a certificate ref using SecCertificateCreateWithData.  From there you can extract a public key ref using a SecTrust object (SecTrustCreateWithCertificates, SecTrustEvaluate -- you can choose to ignore the resulting SecTrustResultType -- and SecTrustCopyPublicKey).  And from there you can encrypt and verify using the SecKey APIs (SecKeyEncrypt, SecKeyRawVerify).

https://devforums.apple.com/message/114555#114555